# Make beamer’s textheight exactly the available size

Tags: beamer

The following code produces an “Overfull \vbox (1.0pt too high)”.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%
    \rule{1cm}{\textheight}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This prevents, e.g., showing graphics (centered and) optimally scaled using simply: `\centering\href{https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/git.png}{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth, height = \textheight, keepaspectratio]{xkcd.png}}` (assuming one wants no warnings).

(I am very surprised that nobody [seems to have noticed this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbeamer%5D+%5Ctextheight+overfull+vbox), is this specific to my setup?)

Also, interestingly, when using headers and footers, the `\textheight` seems to adjust correctly, but is still off one point.

My first question (assuming this is not a problem specific to my set up), out of curiosity, is: why is this off, and why exactly off one point?

My second question, more practical, is: how to solve this?
I realize I can adjust manually the length of `textheight` by susbtracting one point to it before using it, but is there any more elegant solution (that would really compute the available height on the slide in the beamer template, say)?

Comment: If you use `\begin{frame}[plain]%` there is no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is being set as the first line of the first paragraph of the page, so with its reference point `\topskip` *below* the top, it is too tall to fit so you get `\lineskip` glue above it which is 1pt.

You can suppress the space above the line with `\nointerlineskip` (or set `\lineskip` to zero or ...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%

\nointerlineskip
    \rule{1cm}{\textheight}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```